# how to print whole XML using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

i want to grab all link from a url.

but i want it showing in XML.

for example i want to take all link from this url `http://www.example.com/xxxx/`

i want it to print like this:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/yyyy/" target="_blank">anotherxxx</a>`

here my code but i got error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode or null, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sh\index.php:18 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sh\index.php(18): DOMDocument->saveXML('/') #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sh\index.php on line 18

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/xxxx/";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $short_link = $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo $short_link1 = $dom->saveXML($short_link);
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DOMXPath to retrieve all links as

```
$links = $xpath->query("//a/@href");
```

Then loop through links and get its html content as

```
$dom->saveHTML($link)
```

Full code here ..

```
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($this->dom);
$links = $xpath->query("//a/@href");
foreach($links as $link){
     echo $dom->saveHTML($link);
     echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Your selecting the href attributes not the link elements: `//a[@href]` - any `a` element with an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getAttribute()` will return the attributes value as a string.  So if you just want the href then

```
$short_link = $link->getAttribute('href');
echo $short_link;
```

with...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/yyyy/" target="_blank">anotherxxx</a>
```

will give you `http://www.example.com/yyyy/`

If you want the anchor tag itself...

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        echo $dom->saveXML($link);
}
```

Will give

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/yyyy/" target="_blank">anotherxxx</a>
```